# How to design a tall and narrow database table that can deal with unstructured/diverse metadata?

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema, entity-attribute-value, feature-store

I'm designing a database table to store machine learning features (i.e. a feature store) and was thinking to use this tall/narrow schema: `event_date, feature_name, feature_value, creation_date`.

This works for simple features, but seems to fall short on more complex scenarios.

Let's consider an example scenario where we want to store features related to a shop (item purchases, orders cancelled...), we might have features that look like

| event_date | store_name | feature_name | feature_value | creation_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | food_corp | items_sold | 10 | 2021-05-01 |
| 2021-01-02 | food_corp | items_sold | 5 | 2021-05-01 |
| 2021-01-01 | supplements_corp | items_sold | 8 | 2021-05-01 |
| 2021-01-02 | supplements_corp | items_sold | 3 | 2021-05-01 |
| 2021-01-01 | food_corp | orders_cancelled | 2 | 2021-05-01 |

but what if i want to track more granular data, for example product names or customer types? Is the above schema flexible enough? How would i store that additional metadata?

#### Schema proposal 1

This incorporates metadata in the feature name, for example `cheese_item_purchases_french_customer` indicates the purchase of `cheese` item from a `french_customer`, storing these two pieces of metadata in the `feature_name`

| event_date | store_name | feature_name | feature_value | creation_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | food_corp | cheese_item_purchases_french_customer | 9 | 2021-05-01 |
| 2021-01-01 | food_corp | cheese_item_purchases_german_customer | 4 | 2021-05-01 |
| 2021-01-01 | supplements_corp | vitamin_d_item_purchases_french_customer | 7 | 2021-05-01 |
| 2021-01-01 | supplements_corp | vitamin_d_item_purchases_german_customer | 2 | 2021-05-01 |
| 2021-01-01 | food_corp | orders_cancelled_french_customer | 2 | 2021-05-01 |

Seems hard to query and one would need to know the exact structure of the feature_name column

#### Schema proposal 2

Add a metadata column

| event_date | store_name | feature_name | metadata | feature_value | creation_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | food_corp | items_sold | {product_name: cheese, customer_class: french} | 9 | 2021-05-01 |
| 2021-01-01 | food_corp | items_sold | {product_name: cheese, customer_class: german} | 4 | 2021-05-01 |
| 2021-01-01 | supplements_corp | items_sold | {product_name: vitamin_d, customer_class: french} | 7 | 2021-05-01 |
| 2021-01-01 | supplements_corp | items_sold | {product_name: vitamin_d, customer_class: german} | 2 | 2021-05-01 |
| 2021-01-01 | food_corp | orders_cancelled | {customer_class: french} | 2 | 2021-05-01 |

Also seems hard (and inefficient?) to query

#### Schema proposal 3

Uses two tables to store feature values and feature metadata

**feature_store_table**

| event_date | store_name | feature_name_hash | feature_value | creation_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | food_corp | feature_1 | 10 | 2021-05-01 |
| 2021-01-01 | food_corp | feature_2 | 5 | 2021-05-01 |
| 2021-01-01 | supplements_corp | feature_1 | 8 | 2021-05-01 |
| 2021-01-01 | supplements_corp | feature_2 | 3 | 2021-05-01 |
| 2021-01-01 | food_corp | feature_3 | 2 | 2021-05-01 |

**feature_metadata_table**

| feature_name_hash | feature_name | metadata_name | metadata_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| feature_1 | items_sold | product_name | cheese |
| feature_1 | items_sold | customer_class | french |
| feature_2 | items_sold | product_name | cheese |
| feature_2 | items_sold | customer_class | german |
| feature_3 | orders_cancelled | customer_class | french |

Seems the most flexible and clean, but will make queries likely more complex. For example, how do i retrieve all entries in `feature_store_table` having `{'product_name': 'cheese', 'customer_class': 'french'}` ?

---

Of course the alternative to all of this would be to use multiple short/wide tables for each feature but for my use case I'd prefer to stick to a tall/narrow format.

Do you have any recommendation on the proposed approaches or any better ones that i've missed? Regardless of the above premise, should i definitely think to move to multiple short/wide tables?

Thanks

Comment: i would look for all values that have more than 2 character and put them into a tablr and pnly reference the id. schema 3 needs always to be pivot which means a lot of programming so use normalized tables

Comment: what do you mean by "more than 2 character" ? might be missing something trivial here, but feel free to post an answer with an example, thanks anyway!

Comment: food_corp is repeated many times and cists space for every naming, see abourt normalization

Comment: See the EAV tag for many discussions of similar schema designs.